# Public/Private keys for Google developers service account

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-oauth, gspread

I've been going over this for a while and can't manage to understand how to obtain my public/private keys for my automatically created service account in the google developers console.

I am making a python script that imports data using gspread from a google spreadsheet, and to authenticate myself through `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` I need an existent service account

The issue is:

I create a new project using:
["Create a project"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgF7U.png)

But then when I go to Permissions/Permissions, I see that [the service account I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7xNZ.png) is already created, but I don't have the keys for it.

I want to know how to get the `@developer.gserviceaccount.com` keys since I have already tried importing data from google spreadsheets using my other `@xxx-22324.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with no luck, it says the email address does not exist.

**EDIT:**

Whenever I go to API Manager / Credentials I only get the possibility to generate a key for my `@mxxx-22324.iam.gserviceaccount.com` (The one that I can't use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue:

Google has updated its service account detail format and also it's way of sharing Spreadsheets with service accounts so that they can be accessible from gspread.

I created then a service account with the new formating : xxx@montredo-22324.iam.gserviceaccount.com and set the exact same file google generates as a JSON to be read by my application:

```
login = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
```

then shared without notifications the spreadsheet with my service account email (the same in the JSON file I just mentioned)

and voila.